# Laravel dusk 'No tests executed!'

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to run the test that I made with laravel dusk but when I run the command php artisan dusk I get the message that he can't find any tests which I made with php artisan dusk:make. Here is the code of one of my tests:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Browser\Pages\Auth;

use Tests\DuskTestCase;
use Laravel\Dusk\Browser;
use \App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;

class testSignin extends DuskTestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();

        $this->seed();
    }
    /**
     * @tests signin
     * @group auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_Signin()
    {
        $user = factory(User::class)->create();
        $this->browse(function (Browser $browser) use ($user) {
            $browser->visit('/relation')
                ->assertPathIs('/signin')
                ->type('login', $user->username)
                ->type('password', $user->password)
                ->press('Inloggen')
                ->assertPathIs('/relation');
        });
    }
}
```

What is exactly wrong with my code that he can't find my test?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume Dusk is working same way as PHPUnit.

So .... rename your file and class to `SigningTest` (file `SigningTest.php`) and mark action as test `@test`

Comment: If by "action" you mean the method, could you give a code example of what this should look like? This is confusing because in PHP Unit all methods that start with `test_` don't need a `@test`, and on top of that, the ExampleTest generated by `php artisan make:dusk MyTest` command does not include any `@test` statement.